# Problem or ERROR in converting from raster to vector!

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, dem, polygonize

I wonder if anyone could help me out, i am kind of a beginner at QGIS.
I´ve built a DEM for a project that i am developing than i´ve made the slope raster with the terrain analysis,it seemed that worked everything fine. But for further development of my work i ll need to vectorize some slope classes,but unfortunately every time i go Raster>Conversion>Polygonize; i get a error message (image with the error attached to this question).
I thought that could be something wrong with the DEM that i ve produced.Just to check it  i downloaded a DEM from ASTER DEM and  i tried to do same with these and the same error occurs!
Could be a software bug? Or am i doing something wrong?
Or there is another way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: try to avoid non-ascii characters in the output file name. From that I can see you are naming the file to something like `..ECOLÓGICA..`. This should be the fastest way to solve.

Comment: @Irssvt - you were right, it was the name of the folder. i have change it for a simple name and it worked very well. Thanks a lot. It is really appreciated. Regards. Vitor

Comment: @Joseph is there a way to convert a comment to an answer here? or should I simply to answer by pasting the above comment?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear @lrssvt. Yes, I meant copy/paste your comment (with some editing) into an answer. Then delete your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the presence of non-ascii characters in the path of the output file, so you just change the path name to something else that contains ordinary characters (e.g. UTF-8) and try again.